# Android Compose LazyList - keep scrolling position when new items are added to the top of the list

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Here's the original list before I add any new item

[image: Original list]

When I add a new item to the end of the list, without scrolling, the first item still remains in that position

[image: List after adding new items to the end]

But when I add new items to the start of the list, all the old items is moved down. Notice that `New item 0` is not at the very top of the list anymore

[image: List after adding new items to the start]

How can I make it so that if I add a new item to the start of the list, the old item still remain in the exact position. And these new items will only be visible when the user scrolls up, not pushing everything down. If I remember correctly, it's the default behavior with `RecyclerView`

Here's my code:
`MainActivity.kt`

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val list = MutableStateFlow<List<String>>(emptyList())

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            EmptyComposeTheme {
                val items = list.collectAsState()
                Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    LazyColumn(
                        Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    ) {
                        itemsIndexed(items.value) { index: Int, item: String ->
                            Text(item, color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface)
                        }
                    }
                    FloatingActionButton(onClick = {
                        val oldList = list.value.toMutableList()
                        oldList.add("New item ${oldList.size}")
                        list.value = oldList
                    }, Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomStart)) {
                       Text("Click me!")
                    }
                    FloatingActionButton(onClick = {
                        val oldList = list.value.toMutableList()
                        oldList.add(0, "New item reversed ${oldList.size}")
                        list.value = oldList
                    }, Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomEnd)) {
                        Text("Click other me!")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Compose version `1.0.1`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`LazyComun` with `itemsIndexed`and `index` in the key param solved my problem.

```
LazyColumn(
    state = listState
) {
    itemsIndexed(list, key = {index, item->
       index + item.hashcode() // Including index in the key param solved my problem
    }) {
       ....
    }
}
```

Comment: could you provide a reference to explain why it works?

Comment: As per the document: When you specify the key the scroll position will be maintained based on the key, which means if you add/remove items before the current visible item the item with the given key will be kept as the first visible one.

Comment: You should avoid keying by index and prefer to key by something that is specific to each item (which would not change if that item changes position)

Comment: Also - there's a small chance hashCode() could return the same thing for two objects

Answer (score 0):

Basically you aim at controlling the scroll position as described in some more detail [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#control-scroll-position)

While taking your code as a basis, you could hence do the following:

```
val items = list.collectAsState()
val listState = rememberLazyListState()
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    LazyColumn(
        state = listState,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    ) {
        ...
    }
    
    ...
    
    FloatingActionButton(onClick = {
        val currentIndex = listState.firstVisibleItemIndex + 1
        val oldList = list.value.toMutableList()
        oldList.add(0, "New item reversed ${oldList.size}")
        list.value = oldList

        coroutineScope.launch {
            listState.scrollToItem(currentIndex)
        }
    }, Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomEnd)) {
        Text("Click other me!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

u can add key param to LazyColumn like this, but if ur firstVisibleIndex = 0, then problem not solved, i do not know why its:

```
LazyColumn(
    state = listState,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    key = { item -> item.id} // or any unique value
) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).